# Scraping data from websites using VBA. Search bar on website instantly replacing my input

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a website. What I want done is when I input an address from excel such as 'Wangaratta, Victoria', it will acquire that address, and input it into a search bar on this website that looks at the drone flight zones for that address and tells me whether or not I need a flight permit to fly there.

At this stage, I have it working to the point where it opens up the webpage and puts my inputted address from excel into the search bar. Once it's automated to click the search bar, all of a sudden, it replaces my data in the search bar to another address. This address that it replaced mine with is either a random one somewhere in Australia, or it's the last thing I typed into the webpage from the previous time I manually inputted into it. Basically, it only searches for the correct address if I manually input it into the search bar. If it's done with VBA it doesn't recognize it. I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

I've also tried just removing the '.click' command, waiting for the web page to load up, waiting for the input data to go into the search bar and then manually clicking it but that still does not work. Any support would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
Sub NFZChecking()

  Dim Key As String
  Dim Link As String
  
  'Link to the address
  Link = "https://www.uavforecast.com"
 
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim doc As HTMLDocument
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate Link
  
  Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
  Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
  Loop
  
  Set doc = IE.Document
  
  'Address is inputted into separate cells in excel and then merged into one address
  Dim addressNumber As String
  Dim addressStreet As String
  Dim addressState As String
  Dim addressCity As String
  Dim Address As String
   
  addressNumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I4").Value
  addressStreet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I5").Value
  addressState = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I6").Value
  addressCity = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I7").Value
  
  Address = addressNumber + " " + addressStreet + ", " + addressCity + ", " + addressState
  

  'You can just replace Address with any location : "New York". 
  IE.Document.getElementById("address").Value = Address
  
  IE.Document.getElementById("search").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure you use `Option Explicit` all the time. You `Dim Adress As String` but use `Address` (one `d` vesus `dd`). Also string concatenation has to be done with `&` because `+` is only for calculating. • Probably the website has some fancy javascript mechanism working to defend automation.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Is there any way to overcome this fancy JavaScript on this website or has this been put on for a reason?